# Android Image scaling despite being located in HDPI folder (OpenGL error/warning)

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es

I am working on a TV app (where presumably the size limit is 2048x2048) and   i'm having an issue where my image (1920 x 1080) is scaling to different sizes (thus breaking the limit of the OpenGL renderer). When I initially ran the app when the image was located in the base "drawable" folder I'd get this warning:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3840x2160, max=2048x2048)
```

...and it had doubled the images size. So, after some reading up I read that drawable-mdpi was the base (1x) folder, however i'd get the same error with no change of size. I then tried the drawable-hdpi folder and got the error again but with a change of image size:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1440, max=2048x2048)
```

At this point i'm not certain how to keep the image at it's normal (1920 x 1080) size to prevent the image from not rendering; getting the OpenGL renderer error.

I think the reason for it, is something to do with where the image is located in the Android Studio scaling directories(i.e drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi). However, if i'm wrong I'd really like to know why this is occuring (for future usages) and how I can fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this bitmap to be outside of the normal density conversion system, use `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Comment: Will scaling be messed up if I use this?

Comment: And what does anydpi actually mean, does that keep it at it's own dpi?

Comment: @CGI-Demon402: "Will scaling be messed up if I use this?" -- I have no way of knowing. "And what does anydpi actually mean, does that keep it at it's own dpi?" -- an image does not have a density. Putting an image in, say, `drawable-hdpi` says "pretend this image is correct for `hdpi` devices, and upscale/downscale as needed for devices with other densities". `drawable-anydpi` says "this image is fine for any density device without density-based scaling".

Comment: There is no drawable-anydpi in the res directory. How can I access it?

Comment: @CGI-Demon402: It's a directory. You create it like you create any other directory.

Comment: I assumed, thanks though. Appreciate the answer, will mark it as so